# Support with Logic Gate Simulation program in Python

Tags: function, boolean, logic

I'm trying to create a logic gate simulation program in python so that a user can choose the type of logic gate they want to simulate. Once chosen, they can then enter the inputs and the program should return the value of the output from the chosen logic gate to the user.

This is what I have so far:

```
print ("Logic Gate Simulation")

def AND (a,b):

    if a == 1 and b == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0



def NAND (a,b):
    if a == 1 and b == 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1


def OR(a,b):
    if a == 1:
        return 1
    elif b == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def NOR (a,b):
    if a != b:
        return 1
    else:
        return 1

def Main():
    question = input("what type of gate do you want to simulate - OR, AND  or NAND?  ")

    if question == 'AND':
        a = input("enter value for input 1")
        b = input("enter value for input 2")
        x= AND(a,b)
        print (x)

    else:
        print ("")
Main()
```

When I run the program and enter AND, inputs 1 and 1 it still returns 0 and I cant see why.

Answer (score 2):

this works:

```
def AND (a,b):
    a=int(a)
    b=int(b)
    if a == 1 and b == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

you have to tell python that a and b are integers - (there are better ways of doing that than the method shown)

Answer (score 2):

This is my version of the code (I had to this for homework for AS Level, this may help you!) :

```
print("Logic Gate Calculator")


def AND(a, b):  # AND Gate
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    if a == 1 and b == 1:  # AND Gate logic
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def NAND(a, b):  # NAND Gate
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    if a == 1 and b == 1:  # NAND Gate logic
        return 0
    elif a == 1 and b == 0:
        return 0
    elif a == 0 and b == 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1


def OR(a, b):  # OR Gate
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    if a == 1:  # OR Gate Logic
        return 1
    elif b == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def NOR(a, b):  # NOR Gate
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    if a == 1 and b == 0:  # NOR Gate Logic
        return 1
    elif a == 0 and b == 1:
        return 1
    elif a == 0 and b == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def XOR(a, b):  # XOR Gate
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    if a == 1 and b == 0:  # XOR Gate Logic
        return 1
    elif a == 1 and b == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def main():  # The main program
    run = True
    while run:  # While loop
        question = input("What type of gate do you want to use OR, AND, NOR, or NAND or (Q)uit")  # Logic Gate chooser
        if question == "AND" or question == "and" or question == "And":  # If the user selects AND
            a = input("Enter value for input 1 (1 or 0):")  # Getting the Logic Gate's 1st input
            b = input("Enter value for input 2 (1 or 0):")  # Getting the Logic Gate's 2nd input
            x = AND(a, b)  # Calling the AND Function
            print("The output will be:", x)  # Output result
        elif question == "OR" or question == "or" or question == "Or":  # If the user selects OR
            a = input("Enter value for input 1 (1 or 0):")  # Getting the Logic Gate's 1st input
            b = input("Enter value for input 2 (1 or 0):")  # Getting the Logic Gate's 2nd input
            x = OR(a, b)  # Calling the OR Function
            print("The output will be:", x)  # Output result
        elif question == "NOR" or question == "nor" or question == "Nor":  # If the user selects NOR
            a = input("Enter value for input 1 (1 or 0):")  # Getting the Logic Gate's 1st input
            b = input("Enter value for input 2 (1 or 0):")  # Getting the Logic Gate's 2nd input
            x = NOR(a, b)  # Calling the NOR function
            print("The output will be:", x)  # Output result
        elif question == "NAND" or question == "nand" or question == "Nand":  # If the user selects NAND
            a = input("Enter value for input 1 (1 or 0):")  # Getting the Logic Gate's 1st input
            b = input("Enter value for input 2 (1 or 0):")  # Getting the Logic Gate's 2nd input
            x = NAND(a, b)  # Calling the NAND function
            print("The output will be:", x)  # Output result
        elif question == "XOR" or question == "xor" or question == "Xor":  # If the user selects XOR
            a = input("Enter value for input 1 (1 or 0):")  # Getting the Logic Gate's 1st input
            b = input("Enter value for input 2 (1 or 0):")  # Getting the Logic Gate's 2nd input
            x = XOR(a, b)  # Calling the XOR function
            print("The output will be:", x)  # Output result
        elif question == "Q" or question == "q":  # Quiting the program
            run = False
        else:
            print("Please enter one of the shown logic gates")  # Error handling


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

a=True
b=True

output=a and b
print (output)

a=True
b=False

output=a and b
print (output)

Please try this

Comment: the input box is combining lines

Answer (score -1):

It works. Use 
if a == 1:
if b == 1:
return 1
else
return 0